# Connection to mongodb failing from discord bot

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to use the following docker to run using this github repo (https://github.com/Noah-Huppert/discord-azure-boot/)

I have successfully got the bot to connect to my azure instance, however I keep hitting a snag connecting to mongo even after following the advise to change the connection string for the one as part of the stack, to no luck.

I thought I'd build a separate mongodb to see if that would work but still no luck. I feel that I'm literally just missing one small part in the connection string.

Here is the error I'm getting back from the bot:

```
{ message: 'trying to connect to mongodb', level: 'info' }
{
  error: MongoError: Authentication failed.
      at MessageStream.messageHandler (/opt/discord-azure-bot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
      at MessageStream.emit (node:events:520:28)
      at processIncomingData (/opt/discord-azure-bot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
      at MessageStream._write (/opt/discord-azure-bot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
      at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
      at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
      at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
      at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12) {
    ok: 0,
    code: 18,
    codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed'
```

Answer (score 0):

So after simply changing the connection string to

```
      connectionURI: "mongodb://mongo:27017",
```

It actually connected. I feel silly for not trying this sooner.